# XML data to Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, xml, pandas

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1M66WaMkwfkDoFW41MSwuKG4ZHyuSxFrO
[image: preview]
Guys its the first time working with XML. I've read many posts but still cant handle my data. 
In the link there is a part of my data (3 entities (mensaje) induced in the file. original one is about 35.000 entities).
From those data I need to create a pandas dataframe .

Each line of the dt should be refer to one `<mensaje>` 
The first column has to be  `<numerosolicitud>********</numerosolicitud>`
second column `<codigocliente>**********</codigocliente>`
and then i need one column for each `<cuestionario><pregunta cod=***`. There are 98 i think "cod" all same on all "mensajes". I need those "cod" as headers and Text if contained as value.

I believe that it is a basic task but after several days reading tutorials and posts still I need help. Any advice is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for my problem. Probably someone could make something more efficient but this code worked for me.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
tree = ET.parse(r"C:\path\of\your\file")
root = tree.getroot()
df = pd.Dataframe()
counter=1
for mensaje in root.iter('mensaje'):
    df.loc[counter, 'numerosolicitud'] =  mensaje.find(".//numerosolicitud").text if not None else None
    df.loc[counter, 'codigocliente'] =  mensaje.find(".//codigocliente").text if not None else None
    df.loc[counter, 'riesgocb'] =  mensaje.find(".//riesgocb").text    if not None else None
    nodes = mensaje.findall(".//pregunta")
    for child in nodes:
        df.loc[counter, str(child.attrib["cod"] )] =  str((child.text if not None else None))
    print(counter)
    counter+=1

df.to_excel("output.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 2):

I've made a package for similar use case. It could work here too.

```
pip install pandas_read_xml
```

you can do something like

```
import pandas_read_xml as pdx

df = pdx.read_xml('filename.xml', ['data', 'mansaje'])
```

To flatten, you could

```
df = pdx.flatten(df)
```

or

```
df = pdx.fully_flatten(df)
```